# Use a shared controller class for entire area?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a area "Admin" on my mvc application with for each page it's own controller. Like PageController and ModuleController etc. On my shared layout file (View/_Shared/_LayoutAdmin.chtml) the menu gets loaded dynamicly into a @model var. Now in my HomeController I have this method the fetch the menu:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _db.Menus.Include("MenuItems").First(m => m.Name == "Admin menu");
        ViewBag.AdminMenu = new MenuModelView
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            CssClass = model.CssClass,
            CssId = model.CssId,
            Deleted = model.Deleted,
            MenuItems = model.MenuItems
        };

        return View();
    }
```

This block of code is needed on every controller class. I don't think duplicating this code is the best idea. So I was wondering if it is possible to have this method in a shared controller class for the entire Admin area. Like a code behind class for the Shared/_LayoutAdmin.chtml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like a menu that should be repeated throughout a particular area, you want to use a child action:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult AdminMenu()
{
    var menu = _db.Menus.Include("MenuItems").First(m => m.Name == "Admin menu");
    var model = new MenuModelView
    {
        Name = menu.Name,
        CssClass = menu.CssClass,
        CssId = menu.CssId,
        Deleted = menu.Deleted,
        MenuItems = menu.MenuItems
    };

    return PartialView("_AdminMenu", model);
}
```

*I changed your code around a bit so that you actually pass your view model to the view instead of stuffing it in `ViewBag`. Don't use `ViewBag`. It's awful.*

**_AdminMenu.cshtml**

```
@model Namespace.To.MenuModelView

<!-- render your menu and just your menu here -->
```

**Areas\Admin\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml**

```
...

<!-- place this where you want the menu to appear in your layout -->
@Html.Action("AdminMenu", "ControllerNameWhereChildActionExists")

...
```

Comment: But this child action needs to be copied to all controllers within the admin area. That's a lot of duplicate code, not sure if that's what we want.

Comment: Not at all. You just need to put it in one controller, and the call that partucular action and controller in your layout. No duplicate code at all.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can... you can use inheritance to create what is effectively a shared controller class. Like so...

```
Public Class AdminBaseController : Controller {

    public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = _db.Menus.Include("MenuItems").First(m => m.Name == "Admin menu");
            ViewBag.AdminMenu = new MenuModelView
            {
                Name = model.Name,
                CssClass = model.CssClass,
                CssId = model.CssId,
                Deleted = model.Deleted,
                MenuItems = model.MenuItems
            };

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Then you can build all of your other controllers to inherit it, like so:

```
Public Class AdminController1 : AdminBaseController
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I ended up fetching the menu from the constructor in the AdminBaseController class.

Comment: While this is a perfectly valid answer, it's not ideal to rely on all your controllers inheriting from a base controller in order for something like a menu to show on the page. If you forget or a new developer comes along that doesn't know that every controller must inherit from this base controller, then all of a sudden the menu is gone with no obvious reason why. Using a child action is preferable as it just works, no matter what your controller inherits from.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider if I can encapsulate the UI that needs this data in the layout into a partial.  In which case from:

#### _LayoutAdmin.cshtml

```
...
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "AdminLayout")}
...
```

So you would have a `AdminLayoutController` with your Index action and the view which is just a partial view containing your menu.